# How to pass a sealed class through data binding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, viewmodel

I have the following sealed class:

```
sealed class Pot(
    val ball: Ball,
    val potType: PotType,
    val potAction: PotAction
) {
    class HIT(hitBall: Ball) : Pot(hitBall, PotType.HIT, PotAction.CONTINUE)
    object SAFE : Pot(Ball.NOBALL, PotType.SAFE, PotAction.SWITCH)
    object MISS : Pot(Ball.NOBALL, PotType.MISS, PotAction.SWITCH)
    class FOUL(foulBall: Ball, foulAction: PotAction): Pot(foulBall, PotType.FOUL, foulAction)
    class REMOVERED(removeBall: Ball): Pot(removeBall, PotType.REMOVERED, PotAction.CONTINUE)
    object ADDRED: Pot(Ball.RED, PotType.ADDRED, PotAction.CONTINUE)
}
```

I want to pass this from the xml to the view model as such:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.snookerscore.fragments.game.Pot"/>
    // other variables
</data>
```

Then I use lambdas in the views I need to pass the information to the click handler:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_btn_act_safe"
    style="@style/temp_btn"
    android:onClick="@{() -> gameViewModel.updateFrame(Pot.SAFE)}"
    // Other view Properties 
/>
```

I get this error:

> Could not find identifier 'Pot'. Check that the identifier is spelled correctly, and that no  or  tags are missing.

I've also tried importing `Pot.SAFE` directly, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Data binding uses Java to generate codes and in your XMLs you have to code in Java (e.g. ternary conditions are written with `condition ? A : B` instead of Kotlin `if/else`)

So you have to access those object using Java syntax, something like:

```
android:onClick="@{v -> gameViewModel.updateFrame(Pot.SAFE.INSTANCE)}"
```

Comment: I've also spotted that `()` instead of `v` in the beginning of onClick. which may cause some issues (I've updated my answer actually I've copied yours and edited it). Also, when you `Cmd/Ctrl + B` or `Cmd + Click` on `Pot` in import, does it take you to the definition? Probably there’s really a typo in package or something

Comment: This actually worked  in combination with `<import type="com.example.snookerscore.fragments.game.Pot"/>`. I tested both `()` and `v` and they both work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

used;

```
<variable
            name = "sealedName"
            type="com.example.snookerscore.fragments.game.Pot"/>
```

Removed

```
<import type="com.example.snookerscore.fragments.game.Pot"/>
```

final;

```
android:onClick="@{() -> gameViewModel.updateFrame(sealedName.SAFE)}"
```

Comment: I am still getting an error: Could not find accessor com.example.snookerscore.fragments.game.Pot.SAFE